# why doesn't substring function return the newline character(\n)

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find if the first 2 characters of a string contain the newline character using the substring, but for some reason I was the expected result.

```
var xyz= '\n\nsomething';
if(xyz.substring(0,2)=='\n'){
   alert('found');  //expected result
}else{
   alert('not found');  //actual result
}
```

But if I use a regex for this then I get the correct result.

```
var xyz= '\n\nsomething';
if(xyz.substring(0,2).match(/\n/)){
   alert('found');  //actual result and this is correct
}else{
   alert('not found');
}
```

Why do I not get the results when I use the substring function?

Comment: You are taking 2 characters, so it substr(0,2) == "\n\n"

Comment: since the first 2 characters are new line, xyz.substring(0,2) will return you 2 new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string that you get from `xyz.substring(0, 2)` is not `"\n"` but `"\n\n"`.

When you use the escape sequence `\n` that will end up as a single character in the string, not the separate characters `\` and `n`.

If you are looking for the first character, use `1` as length:

```
if (xyz.substring(0,1) == '\n') {
```

If you are matching the two first characters, put two characters in the string:

```
if (xyz.substring(0,2) == '\n\n') {
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the newline *character* is exactly that -- one character:

```
var xyz= '\n\nsomething';
if (xyz.substring(0, 1) == '\n'){
   alert('found');
} else {
   alert('not found');
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/M54D3/

Answer (score 1):

\n is actually only one character. Try using:

```
xyz.substring(0,1)=='\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using `substring(0, 2)`, this creates a **2**-characters-long string.
Therefore, `if (xyz.substring(0,2) == '\n') {` will not match because `'\n\n' != '\n'`.

Instead, try using **regex**, or **contains**:

```
// regex
// \n in first character, or \n in second character, no need to substring
if(xyz.match(/^(\n|.\n)/)) {
   alert('found');
} else{
   alert('not found');
}
```

.

```
// contains
if(xyz.substring(0,2).contains('\n')) {
   alert('found');
} else{
   alert('not found');
}
```

Both give the same results, choose the one you think that looks nicer, performance differences are too small to consider, but the second one is a little bit faster.